# searchable dropdown option is now showing when click add new row in vue js

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I want to search from dropdown with select2 jquery plugin with Vuejs but in the first row the search option is working perfectly fine but when i add the second row the search option is not showing just the drop down list showing

[blade view file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeJYk.png)
[addrowcontact funtion where the row is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW5WB.png)